# Reading data from a firebase database snapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, I'm trying to take a snapshot of my Database and add the items with its child's in array-strings.

[image: My database looks like this]

My main activity looks like this

```java
    private Button mbutton;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_advanced_search);
        mbutton = findViewById(R.id.button_search);
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                goListener();
            }
        });
    }
    private void goListener() {
        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                dataQuery(snapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
    private void dataQuery(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (int y = 0; y !=2; y++) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                AdvancedQuery findInfo = new AdvancedQuery();
                findInfo.setName(ds.child(String.valueOf(y)).getValue(AdvancedQuery.class).getName());
                findInfo.setIngredients(ds.child(String.valueOf(y)).getValue(AdvancedQuery.class).getIngredients());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my set and get java file looks like this

```java
public class AdvancedQuery {
    public String name, ingredients;
    public AdvancedQuery(){ }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }
    public void setIngredients(String ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }
}
```

However, when my program gets to the dataQuery method and tries get and set the name and ingredients, it crashes. Can someone explain what I've done wrong and if there are any better ways to do this with database snapshot?

> Process: in.tvac.akshayejh.firebasesearch, PID: 24798
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String in.tvac.akshayejh.firebasesearch.AdvancedQuery.getName()' on a null object reference
>           at in.tvac.akshayejh.firebasesearch.AdvancedSearch.dataQuery(AdvancedSearch.java:140)
>           at in.tvac.akshayejh.firebasesearch.AdvancedSearch.access$500(AdvancedSearch.java:20)
>           at in.tvac.akshayejh.firebasesearch.AdvancedSearch$2.onDataChange(AdvancedSearch.java:115)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:183)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: Adding the crashlog may help us helping you.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @Traendy I've inlcuded the error logs on the post above.

Comment: @AlexMamo, I've inlcuded the error logs on the post above.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the code where you set the adapter.

Comment: Next up `String.valueOf(i)`. What is the value of `i`? (since your loop is using `y`)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen leftover from previous iteration, changed it now. However, it is not the one causing problems.

Comment: This is the second problem in the code that is distracting from the real problem. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *now* instead of waiting until your next problem.

Comment: What's the output in your logcat if you `System.out.println(ds.getValue())`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the original post. It seems like it reads through the database, however with some problems.It looks like it bugs on a long Text I have stored in there. Here are the logs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz1gP.png

Comment: If I delete the longText on my database and then the two lines ```findInfo.setName(ds.child(String.valueOf(y)).getValue(AdvancedQuery.class).getName());
                findInfo.setIngredients(ds.child(String.valueOf(y)).getValue(AdvancedQuery.class).getIngredients());```
```System.out.println(ds.getValue())``` prints the whole database with no problems or crashes, so the problem should lie within those two commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to parse what your `` is doing. The idiomatic approach is to read only the `Recipes` node, and then loop over the child nodes under there with `snapshot.getChildren()`.

So something like:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Recipes");

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot recipeSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            AdvancedQuery findInfo = recipeSnapshot.getValue(AdvancedQuery.class);

            ...

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // NEVER ignore errors
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you're not initializing `myRef` anywhere, which would lead to a `NullPointerException` when you do `myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...`.

If that is indeed the error you get, make sure to initialize `myRef` before using it, with something like:

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Recipes");
```

I'm not entirely sure if the `.child("Recipes")` is needed, so remove/modify to fit your data model and the logic of your code.

Comment: Hey, sorry my bad I forgot to add it on the code on my post but I do
     mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

Comment: Thanks for confirming. In that case, that leaves the questions from Traendy and Alex about what the actual crash is. I also highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it'd prevent from missing the statement that I answered about.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I'll make sure to consult it in the future. I've added the crash logs but to be honest I cant make much of it.